# How to use javax.jpa.criteriaQuery to query two root entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Since the `hibernate.criteria` API is deprecated, I need assistance in converting certain methods to JPA `criteriaQuery` calls.

The simpler calls with singular criteria and limited parameters I can handle, but how can I convert from a hibernate criteria created with multiple root entities such as

```
Criteria crit = 
session.createCriteria(getType())
.createCriteria("deviceInfo"
.createCriteria("deviceSize");
crit.add(Restrictions.ilike("upperName", modelName));

List<Device> matches = crit.list();
```

The two entity roots created by layered calls to `createCriteria` is where my problems are. How can I double root entities with `javax.jpa.criteriaQuery`?